# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'isVisible'

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I'm trying to display an image using JS and EaselJS.

I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'isVisible'`

Here are my code snippets...

```
        function init() {                               
            canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas"); 
            start();
        }

        function start() {
            //Create new stage and point it at Canvas
            stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");

            myImg = new Image();
            myImg.src = "./Images/SnakeHead.png";
```

Any thoughts why?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you added the image to the stage ?

Answer (score 0):

[From this page](http://community.createjs.com/discussions/easeljs/573-has-no-method-isvisible)

This error usually happens when you add something to the stage that is not a display object. In your code you are using

```
Icon.prototype = new Container()
```

Have you overridden the createjs namespace? If not, the code should be

```
Icon.prototype = new createjs.Container();
```

If this is the issue, then you aren't properly extending Container, which would explain the error.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I would use that given the current image code I have above? I've already read that source and didn't understand it